# Concatenation of two char array C

Tags: c, arrays, string, pointers, char

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  char *s = argv[1];
  *(s + (strlen(argv[1]))) = argv[2];
  printf("%s \n", s);
  return 0;
}
```

when I run: `./concat hello, world` the output is:
`hello,Mworld` while I expect
`hello,world`

What is the `M` char? And why C put this?

Comment: You really need to get the basics first.

Comment: Somebody into unreadable code. Perhaps missing strcpy there along with other things

Comment: printf("%s%s", &argv[1], &argv[2]); should be enough.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are not appending here:

```
   *(s+(strlen(argv[1])))=argv[2];
```

You are assigning a `char*` to the null byte of of `argv[1]` i.e. it's equivalent to

```
 argv[0][strlen(argv[1])] = argv[2];
```

This is wrong and turn up your compiler warnings to get proper diagnostics. In general, to concatenate strings, you need use [`strcat`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strcat.3.html) or [`snprintf`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/printf.3.html).

In this specific case, you can't use `strcat` or `snprint` as the arguments to `main()` do not have additional memory to append. So you need use an auxiliary array or an `malloc'ed pointer to do the concatenation.

You should also check if there are enough arguments passed to `main()` before attempting to use them.

Note that, you can modify the `argv[x]`. For example, if you execute as:

```
./a.out stack overflow
```

then you can do:

```
argv[1][1] = 'l'; 
//argv[1] is now "slack"
```

and so on, as long as you don't go beyond the its boundary. Basically you can treat like a pointer an array which you can modify.

**C11, 5.1.2.2.1  Program startup, p2** states

> The parameters argc and **argv and the strings pointed to by the argv
>   array shall be modiﬁable by the program**, and retain their last-stored
>   values  between program startup and program termination.

(emphasis mine)

Answer (score 0):

You assuming that `argv[1]` is large enough to contain `argv[1]` and `argv[2]`, which could be incorrect.

It would be better to allocate a result buffer to hold the concatenated string, and avoid tampering the input value as much a possible ( this would help you later when writing more complex code).

And if you are modifying your inputs, make no assumption about their size (depending on the implementation `argv[1]` could possibly be large enough to hold the parameter string and writing outside of mean writing parts of memory adjacent to `argv[1]` , which could be used by other data from another process ).

You probably wanted to save some memory and some processor cycle by recycling the memory, but you didn't check  if the variable could hold your result.

Comment: You are missing that the OP's code fails because it doesn't actually do any string concatenation...

Answer (score 0):

The 'M' is the low byte of the address of the second string.

The strings happen to be stored sequentially in memory with the terminating null of the first immediately preceding the second.  (I don't believe that is a rule you are supposed to depend on, though I also don't know of cases where it would be untrue).  You are overwriting that terminating null with the garbage value of implicitly casting the address of the second string as a char.  So you end up with that garbage character between the two parts of the result.